# Why use " " and not ' ' for outputting a blank?

Tags: java

Is there any reason why you may want to use " " and not ' ' to output blanks in Java (any version)?

In *"Data Structures and Problem Solving Using Java (4th Edition)"* by Mark Allen Weiss, it says that it is a common error to not use " " instead of ' ': i.e. We should use " ".

As far as I know, there are no differences between the two.

Trying:

```
System.out.println("a b c" + ' ' + "d e f");
System.out.println("a b c" + " " + "d e f");
```

There seems to be no difference in the output.

Comment: It depends if you need a String or a char.

Comment: My mistake, was working in Python prior to this and forgot about 'char' and "String" difference associated with the two quotation mark types. 
However, I still believe it shouldn't make a difference if you're just joining two Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your example if may have no effect. However, there are cases where it matters.

`char` is an integral type, and

```
System.out.println(1 + ' ' + 2); //output: 35 because 1 + 32 + 2
```

produces a different result from

```
System.out.println(1 + " " + 2); //output: 1 2
```

So you should make sure you know the difference between `' '` and `" "`.

I imagine that the context of the advice in the book gives some indication of what situation it is talking about.

Comment: It only gave an example a bit later :)
I now understand, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is because `+` operator has two meanings in Java

1. **concatenation** if *at least one* operand is String like `Str + ...` or `... + Str`
2. **addition** if *both* operands are *numeric types*:

   - all primitives, except boolean (no in Java `true` and `false` are not equivalents of `1` and `0`),
     BUT including `char` which numeric value is position of character in Unicode Table like `'A'` is [`65`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0041/) and space `' '` is [`32`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0020/).
   - wrapper classes for numeric primitive types like Integer, Double

So if you have `num + Str` operator `+` will represent *concatenation* and you will get String.

But in case of `num + char` operator `+` will represent *addition* and will return numeric value like `System.out.println(1+' ')` will be treated as `1+32` so `33` will be printed.

So if you use `" "` with `+` you are guaranteed that it will be *concatenation*, while meaning of `+` with `' '` will depend on second argument.

Answer (score 0):

We use single quotes for literal chars and double quotes for literal Strings. So you're going to add them together with this:

```
System.out.println("a b c" + ' ' + "d e f");
```

but there is no error in it. You can use " " or ' ' to output a space.

Comment: "*You can use " " or ' ' to output a space*" not always, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694399 to see cases which shows difference in output when we use `" "` vs `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Java book tells you that double quotes is better than single quotes is that `' '` is a `char`, and `" "` is a `String`. This is built-in java behaviour.
`char` is a java primitive, like an `int` or a `float`.  `String` is a supplied object type, not a primitive.  When you put `" "` in your code, java interprets this as an instance of  `java.lang.String`.

You're right that it has no practical effect in your example though. That's because when you concatenate strings and characters, java automatically converts the whole thing to a String (the `+` operator does this).  You can also concatenate other primitives in this way.

However, these are actually quite different in Java, and you can prove this with a simple test:

```
@Test
public void testCharVsString(){
    assertTrue(" ".equals(' '));
}
```

The above test will fail, as these two objects are not the same.

As a general rule it's OK to stick with `String`s when representing characters.  `char` is useful for more advanced coding tasks.

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree with your last paragraph. It may be good to stick with `String` when *printing* specific characters, but I wouldn't encourage people to use `String` to represent a single character in algorithms or business logic.

Comment: Agreed :) I probably should have said "where there might be more than one character". I wanted to keep the language accessible for a new coder.  But you're absolutely right of course - and that's why I hinted at "more advanced coding tasks"